# Keras: How to calculate loss between different layers?

Tags: keras, loss

I wanna calculate loss between different layers, such as the MSE loss between two layers, besides loss between my predict and golden output.
So how to calculate it ?

For example,

```
input = Input(shape=inputsize)
output1 = Dense(50)(input)
output2 = Dense(50)(input)
...
```

I want to add MSE loss between output1 and output2 to the final loss.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGtr6.png)

In this network architecture, I want to ask the yellow shared embedding and grey private embedding to be orthogonal, so I want to add loss between them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "between the two layers", since the two are not connected. Right now you have two outputs connected directly to the input layer.

Comment: If I define the loss like model.compile(loss='mse'), I can just consider the loss between my final predict and golden output. But in my work, I want to make output1 and output2 orthogonal in order to capture different features to achieve  better performance. And I want to use this loss in multitask learning to make different layers learn different features.